# Graphing Quadratic Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help with $f(x)=(x-3)^2$. My teacher said the $x$ intercept is $3$. I don't understand how it   can be positive $3$ when it is negative $3$ in the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

The $x$-intercepts are the points where $f(x)=0$, i.e., where the graph touches the $x$-axis. You have $f(3)=(3-3)^2=0$, so you have an $x$-intercept at $x=3$.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it.

Answer (score 2):

$x$-interscepts are when the function intersects the $x$ axis, i.e. when $f(x)=0$.  Thus

$$0=(x-3)^2 \implies 0=x-3\implies {x=3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Lets graph it and see what happens.

[image]

Do you see why $f(x) = 0$ at $x=3$ now?

Comment: Simple, but *effective*! +1

Comment: I just noticed this morning that as of the close of yesterday/start of the current MSE day, I'm 9 votes away from a gold badge for 1K upvotes in algebra/precalculus ;-)  I'd be "prouder" if it were in "logic"...still have 200 + upvotes to go in that tag, though :-|

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, the algebra/precal tagged questions can present challenges: not so much a math workout, but a challenge for teaching at the appropriate level, and doing so without being condescending!

Comment: @amWhy: I have found that sometimes the other MSE'ers give a lot of feedback regarding their own biases on them! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The x-intercept is the value that you can plug in for x and have f(x) come out to 0. Try evaluating f(3), and see what happens.

Since f(3)=0, that means the point (3,0) is on the graph, so it is an x-intercept.

Seeing the minus sign inside the parentheses can be confusing, because it makes you think of a negative number, but remember to ask, "what value of x would make this equal 0?"

Answer (score 1):

The $x$ intercepts are the abscissa of intersection points of the curve with the $x$ axis. When the curve intersects the $x$ axis, the ordinate is always equal to 0.

[image]

The code to generate the graph can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/5zuET7GB).

Therefore, we have the following equation:

$$
(x-3)^2=0
$$

We have a theorem as follows.

> The solution of  $$ A \times B =0 $$
>
> is $A=0$ with any $B$ *OR* any $A$ with $B=0$.

Thus, the solution of $(x-3)^2=(x-3)(x-3)=$ is $x-3=0$ or $x=3$.